# AWS django Invalid HTTP_HOST header

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I'm depolying my app onto Elasticbeanstalk. When I visit the url, I get Invalid HTTP_HOST header:'mysite.com'.

I've added my url to my settings.py.

This is my settings file:

```
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com/','.mysite.com/', '127.0.0.1:8000', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'localhost:8000', '13.59.177.101', '127.0.0.1']
```

This is my python.config file:

```
    container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate &&python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "project.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "/opt/python/current/app/project/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"

packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []
```

My code works locally without any problem. Not sure what to do. Please help!

Comment: you just need to add host like `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com','localhost','13.59.177.101']` don't need slashes in the host name

Comment: Thanx so much @Rajan, it worked! Really appreciate it